# Combine attributes using sql vba access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a sql statement that want to combine FirstName and LastName together while a listbox retrieve from a table.

```
rs.open"Select ID,Join(FirstName,LastName),Sex from TblPerson "
Set listbox.Recordset=rs
```

I know i use Join() it's wrong, but i just want to explain my purpose.
Thank you in advanced !!

Comment: Irrelevant to the problem, but you should probably use "Gender" instead of "Sex" as the column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate with code like this:

`"SELECT ID, FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS FullName, Sex FROM TblPerson"`

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or higher then this will also work (based on your "access" tag, I assume you aren't):

`"SELECT ID, CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName) AS FullName, Sex FROM TblPerson"`

Comment: For VBA Access the first one is really useful !!